# Can the confirmation URL be different based on different selections made using conditionals?

Tags: 8, webforms

Hello all of you super helpful people. :)

Drupal 8

Webform: Version: 8.x-5.19

I have created a webform which requires the person completing the form to select one of 4 options and whatever they select determines what fields they see or not.

One of the fields, when selected, needs to take the person to a different URL upon submission, but I am having a difficult time finding out if this is even possible to do...

EXAMPLE

Select:

- Home (submit button takes you to the confirmation page)
- Work (submit button takes you to the confirmation page)
- Campaign (submit button would take you to a different URL (internal or external)

Does this make sense? Is this even possible to do?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is nothing out of the box that will support this
the good news it is quite straight forward in a custom module.

in this example
i have admin/structure/webform/manage/WEBFORMID/settings/confirmation

Confirmation type:
-> Page (redirects to new page and displays the confirmation message)
aka normal in your case for "Home" and "Work"

then you need a custom module to do ...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // You will need your $form_id.
  // dump($form_id);
  if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_test1_add_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYODULE_test_form_submit';
  }
}
/**
 * Implements hook_form_submit(). ish.
 */
function MYODULE_test_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_values = $form_state->getValues();
  // this needs to be your element key.
  if (!empty($form_values['select_one'])) {
    if ($form_values['select_one'] === 'campaign') {
      // Redirect to some page
      $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', [
        'node' => 7
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```